# Extracting Sub-String from String?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, ipad, nsstring

I need to extract a string from a string. Only trouble is working out how to specifically in my case.

Lets say this is the master string:

```
City = My City;
Street = My Street 1\nMy Street 2;
```

So, I would want to extract these three things separately:
`My City`, `My Street 1` and `My Street 2`.

So I how would I do so?

Comment: Basically you have some format of string and you wanna parse it? Have you had a look at NSString's documentation?

Comment: what is City ?? City or Street both're separate strings, you just want to separate Street now ?

Comment: The first chunk is a singular string with linebreaks, colons etc, and I want to retrieve three new strings from that master string.

Comment: Just write your master string and tell from where you want to separate it ... Your question is little confusing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use componentsSeparatedByString:<#(NSString *)#> method of the String, it will give you Array of Split Strings.

In your case, Do

```
NSArray * array = [YourString componentsSeparatedByString:@" = "];
```

At [array objectAtIndex:2] you will find "My Street 1\nMy Street 2;" (considering String starts as "My Street 1\nMy Street 2;")

Then you can again Split them by <#(NSString *)#> in your case @"\n"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand your question

To separate a string in substring you can use

```
[[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] lastObject];
```

to get the second part of the adresse. Apply same to get the first object but not by using lastObject.

But i'm not sure to understand your question